# VbA Delete sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete all the sheets which do not equal specific code names but instead of doing that, my code is deleting the sheets that I want to keep.the coding is below:

```
For each ws In wb.worksheets

If ws.CodeName <> “Tasks_Complete” And ws.CodeName <> “Issues_Tasks” Then
ws.Delete
End If

Next ws
```

Instead it deletes the sheets with the code names and keep the sheet that I do not want. Am I missing something from the code?

Comment: Do you have those "smart quotes" in your actual code?  Otherwise that looks fine.

Comment: @TimWilliams, ye I have the smart quotes. I figured how to do it, I changed it to ws.Name <> Tasks_Complete.Name Then ws.Delete and it worked for me

Comment: Just for clarity, Tim is saying that your quote character `“` is different than the default quote character `"`

Answer (score 1):

You have "smart quotes" in your posted code - those are not the same as regular double-quotes.

`Select Case` is maybe easier to read:

```vb
For each ws In wb.worksheets
    Select case ws.CodeName
        Case "Tasks_Complete", "Issues_Tasks"  'do nothing
        Case Else: ws.Delete
    End select
Next ws
```